# Similar Text php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i have the following code that when i search for a word it shows me a did you mean.  the issue is if i type in "clin" i want it to return clinicals but it returns "reschedule"

```
$my_word = $_POST['value'];
$bestMatch = array('word' = > $my_word, 'match' = > 2);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT keyword FROM athena");
$storeArray = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    similar_text($row['keyword'], $my_word, $percent);
    if ($percent > $bestMatch['match'])
       $bestMatch = array('word' = > $row['keyword'], 'match' = > $percent);
}
if ($bestMatch['match'] < 70)
   echo 'Did you mean: <strong>'.$bestMatch['word'].'</strong>';
```

Comment: Is that last if supposed to be `< 70` or `> 70` and is it inside or outside the `while` statement?

Comment: it is outside the while statement

Comment: like i just tessted inputting "temp" and it output did you mean"exam"...and template is in my keywords... ugh

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Can you try limiting your keyword pool and then either echo'ing every comparison, or building a complete array of comparisons (one for each returned row) and verify that the percentages appear to be sane?

Comment: I'm not familiar with similar_text, but I used levenstein in conjunction with soundex and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code with a small set of test entries and it worked fine. Maybe you are getting strange results from your query? Here is the code:

```
$my_word = $_REQUEST['value'];
$bestMatch = array('word' => $my_word, 'match' => 2);
$result = array("exam", "clinicals", "templates", "reschedule", "crafting", "php", "answer");
$storeArray = Array();
foreach ($result as $keyword) {
    similar_text($keyword, $my_word, $percent);
    if ($percent > $bestMatch['match'])
       $bestMatch = array('word' => $keyword, 'match' => $percent);
}
if ($bestMatch['match'] < 70)
   echo 'Did you mean: <strong>'.$bestMatch['word'].'</strong> p:'.$bestMatch['match'];
```

In any case `similar_text()` is probably not the right function for this because it often yields misleading results on **short strings/words**.

As it has already been pointed out, you should use `levenshtein()` for such a task. It calculates how many changes must be made to match the words, where removing, adding and changing a character is a change. You can (and should in this case) **modify the cost for changing to 2**, to get better results with short strings.

The levenshtein function is less costly in terms of performance than similar_text but it will not return a result in percent!

The code for the **levenshtein** approach:

```
$my_word = $_REQUEST['value'];
$bestMatch = array('word' => $my_word, 'match' => 2);
$result = array("exam", "clinicals", "templates", "reschedule", "crafting", "php", "answer");
$storeArray = Array();
foreach ($result as $keyword) {
    $lev = levenshtein ($keyword, $my_word, 1, 2, 1);
    if (!isset($lowest) || $lev < $lowest) {
       $bestMatch = array('word' => $keyword, 'match' => $lev);
       $lowest = $lev;
    }
}
if ($bestMatch['match'] > 0)
   echo 'Did you mean: <strong>'.$bestMatch['word'].'</strong> l:'.$bestMatch['match'];
```

Comment: How do i array my database iwth this lol.. for some reason i keep getting an error.

Comment: does my code work for you? try your version and print out the keywords that you get from the db.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `similar_word()` with PHP, but you can also try the following:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php  which is a popular algorithm for doing the type of search you want.